# What exactly requests function does?

Tags: python, python-requests, html, urllib

So I`m trying to send a request to a webpage and read its response. I did a code that compares the request and the page, and I cant get the same page text. Am I using "requests" correctly?
I really think that I misunderstand how requests function works and what it does. Can someone help me please?

```
 import requests
 import urllib

 def search():
         pr = {'q':'pink'}
         r = requests.get('http://stackoverflow.com/search',params=pr)
         returntext = r.text
         urllibtest(returntext)

 def urllibtest(returntext):
         connection = urllib.urlopen("http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=pink")
         output = connection.read()
         connection.close()
         if output == returntext:
                 print("ITS THE SAME PAGE")
         else:
                 print("ITS NOT THE SAME PAGE")

 search()
```

Comment: `urllib.urlopen` should be `urllib.request.urlopen`

Comment: @Barmar not in Python 2.

Comment: Great first question!

Answer (score 1):

First of all, there is no good reason to expect two different stack overflow searches to return the exact same response anyway.

There is one logical difference here too, requests automatically decodes the output for you:

```
>>> type(output)
str
>>> type(r.text)
unicode
```

---

You can use the `content` instead if you don't want it decoded, and use a more predictable source to see the same content returned - for example:

```
>>> r1 = urllib.urlopen('http://httpbin.org').read()
>>> r2 = requests.get('http://httpbin.org').content
>>> r1 == r2
True
```

Comment: I was going to post that as an answer, but I actually looked at the decoded output from `urllib.request.urlopen` (I'm on python 3) and it was different for me than what I got from `requests.get` . Not sure what to make of that.

Comment: Well, you might have hit the CAPTCHA or something.  There is no good reason to expect the response from two `StackOverflow` searches to return the same content at two different times.

Comment: True, and actually, I think that's exactly what happened: `<title>Human Verification - Stack Overflow</title>`